# How do I highlight the beginning of the block in vim?

Tags: vim, vimscript

My current vim config ([YADR](https://github.com/skwp/dotfiles)) shows the beginning bracket highlighted (only) when I am on the ending one and vice versa. Is there a way to get the same functionality for block beginning and endings, like when I am on the if, highlight else and end, if I am on a function do highlight the end (i.e. in ruby).

The information for what is the beginning and the end of a block should already exist for syntax highlighting or folding, shouldn't it? Is there a way to enable this generally for all languages that are "supported"  (I don't know what would qualify as this. ctags? syntax highlighting scheme?  Sorry I am not that familiar with the internals of vim yet)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably referring to the default *matchparen* plugin, which highlights `(` and the corresponding `)`; see `:help matchparen`.

There is no general solution for other (larger) pairs (such as `begin` .. `end`). However, there exist some special solutions for particular filetypes, e.g. [MatchTag](https://github.com/gregsexton/MatchTag) for opening / closeing HTML tags.